# Looking for a good exposition - Rees Construction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, hodge-theory

Can someone point me in the direction of a good exposition of the Rees Construction in Hodge Theory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many excellent references. It really depends on what you are after. One of the most comprehensive references is the thesis of Olivier Penacchio: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0307156.

Comment: brilliant! I'll have a read